# EXM databases setup - minimal rights

Tags: exm, sql-database

I am upgrading my Sitecore isntance from 9.0 initial to update-1. In this process I had to deploy the databases for EXM (exm.master and messaging) as that is new in this version. I used the dacpac's from the upgrade package as mentioned in the guide.

Although not mentioned in the upgrade guide, I added the sql user (used for the other databases) to these and added:

- read/write rights on both databases
- execute rights on the exm.master database

This seems to work now.. but does anybody know if this is correct? What are the minimal rights that are needed for the user in my connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the EXM Master and Messaging Databases specifically, the only permissions you **must have** are read/write permissions and EXECUTE on both databases.   While there are no stored procedures in those databases that would require the EXECUTE permission, there . Additionally, I am not aware of any TRUNCATE needs.

Alternatively, for things like the Analytics Databases, the Sitecore DB user ***does*** need EXECUTE and TRUNCATE permissions because things like Rebuilding the Reporting Database uses stored procedures and truncation.

But for EXM specifically, the read/write permissions (which should give you the standard CRUD operations) and EXECUTE should be enough.

Comment: On my exm.master I needed to add execute right to get rid of errors in the logs..

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: Failed to remove obsolete sessions - The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SessionIDs', database '...Exm.master'

Comment: I have the same error as @Gatogordo. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Add the execute permissions, that should solve it